# Need to convert password protected Lotus 1-2-3 v4 file

Tags: spreadsheet, password-protection, lotus-1-2-3

I have a Lotus 1-2-3 version 4 password protected file that I need to open. However, I don't have Lotus 1-2-3. I have not found a converter that will convert a password protected file.  Any suggestions?